# Updating the ViewState before the Load event of the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate

Is there any way to update the ViewState from a page event (such as a button click) BEFORE the Load event of the page?

I understand that the event handlers only get called after the load events, but is there any way around this?

Comment: its control view state or user defined view state

Comment: If data is not sensitive, then you can use `asp:HiddenFields` and update it with JQuery

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam user defined view state

Comment: @Soaring_Lion so what is the problem there, just get the value of viewstate with correct casting update it with your value and re-assign it to your viewstate

Comment: @Soaring_Lion see i have given a sample there

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam I need to update the page in the Page Load event with the information added to the ViewState on a button click. The button click happens after page load - thus the information is not yet present at page load.

Comment: @Soaring_Lion " update the page in the Page Load event with the information added to the ViewState on a button click"  Conflicting statement, when to update, on page load or on btnclick

Comment: @Soaring_Lion Why not update in the button click event? That is why it is there.

Comment: Please read and understand the [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

Comment: @Arshad This method seems to work best. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the life-cycle of an ASP .net page. The only way to pass state to the server that can be accessed OnPageLoad is by using a HiddenField on the page which is updated on the client-side with Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ViewState["val"] != null)
        {
            int s = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["val"]);
        }
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ViewState["val"] != null)
        {
            int s = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["val"]);
            s = s + 5;
            ViewState["val"] = s;
        }
        else
        {
            ViewState["val"] = 6;
        }
    }
```

This is the code i tested on my machine 
and on page load i am getting the updaetd value each time,

Comment: This is what I do. But this event only fires AFTER page load. Thus the view state that is read during page load does not yet contain the information added in this method - that is the problem.

Comment: so what you basically need, if the page loading first time , no viewstate there, because its viewstate is for page only, please be more specific

Comment: and yes every event after page load, but still you wont have any problem, its throwing for some object reference error, then be sure you have check for null , and if its null simply assign values to viewstate

Comment: I still don't think you understand the problem. With your answer the ViewState would be 1 "step" behind each time you click the button. If val starts at 0. Then on click 0: button updates val to 5 but page load will still read 0. On click 1: button updates val to 10 but page load will read 5. This can be solved by reading the view state on Pre Render - but in my case I need to read that state long before that.

Comment: @Soaring_Lion , please see the updated answer, the answer i posted i first tested on my machine

Comment: could be the reason you forget to re-assign values to viewstate

Comment: That method still delays the on page update by 1 click. The same as this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20370662/delay-when-reading-data-from-viewstate .

Comment: I suggest you to create a simple test page and then test the code i gave, i have done the similar on my side, and on each button click when i put the debugger on page load , I m getting the update values

Comment: Ok Ok i Understand Your problem